# Basic video editing software to postprocess videos created by Open Broadcaster

Tags: windows, video-editing

I am creating some tutorial videos in [Open Broadcaster](https://obsproject.com/) and I stream them using Silverlight web app to clients after converting them using [Convertilla](http://convertilla.com/) to MP4 format.

It is working very well, but **I miss some basic video editing software** that would allow me to cut parts of video files created by OpenBroadcaster (flv) and to join two separate video files. I sometimes make a mistake and it is easier to cut it out than to do the whole tutorial again.

Tried AviDemux 2.6, but it is quite complicated and does not work well for me.

I would like this software to be compatible with Windows and prefer freeware.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two software for this if you are looking for something really simple and free.

First one is **[Free Video Editor](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Dub.htm#.VlL1k_krLIU)**.

- Delete unwanted parts from video files without re-encoding(preserves original quality )
- Input video formats supported: ***.avi, *.mpg, *.mp4, *.mkv, *.flv, *.3gp, *.webm, *.wmv.**
- Free and absolutely safe

And the second one is **[Free Easy Video Joiner](http://www.freeease.net/v-videojoiner/overview.php)**

- Join videos of different formats or bitrates to a bigger on.
- Format Supported- **AVI, DivX, MP4, FLV, MOV, MPEG, WMV, ASF, etc.**
- Freeware

Hope this resolves the issue now!!!! Cheers!!!

Comment: I need video editing software for .flv or eventually .mp4 (H.264 codec I believe) that would allow deleting selected parts and joining two videos. Neither of proposed software does this or I cannot find the functions, but from your description it is not there. I have found this http://www.machetesoft.com/ and it does what I need but the Lite version does not work with FLV.

Comment: If this software has the required functions it would be useful to add a short description, how to e.g. delete a selected part of a file or to join two files. Also I can imagine running command line with parameters like `videoeditor.exe - file video.flv -delete '1:23:00-1:25:30'`

Comment: Okay i ll update my answer these both aren't working for me either there may be a bug in the software every time i use the crop function it crashes i m sorry for the trouble.